# Convergence of $\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{2m-1}{4m^2-4m-3}\sin[ (2m-1)x]$

Tags: functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, fourier-series

I was reading this [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1162918/computing-the-fourier-series-of-f-cos2x), and made a wrong contribution which I deleted. Now I would like to understand things. Here is the problem:

Consider $f(x)=\cos 2x$ on $[0,\pi]$:

[image]

$f(x)$ is not even on $[0,\pi]$.

$$a_m=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos 2x \cos mx =\frac{2}{\pi}\frac{m \sin m \pi}{m^2-4}=0,m=0,1,3,4,5...$$

and $a_2=1$. But for $m$ odd we have

$$b_m=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_0^{\pi}\cos 2x \sin mx =\frac{4}{\pi}\frac{2m-1}{4m^2-4m-3}$$

and for $m$ even we have $b_m=0$.
Now I define the following function:
\begin{align}
F(x)&=\frac{2}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{m (1-\cos m \pi)}{m^2-4}\sin [mx]\\
&=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{2m-1}{4m^2-4m-3}\sin [(2m-1)x]
\end{align}

Now define $\displaystyle F_n(x)=\frac{4}{\pi}\sum_{m=1}^{n}\frac{2m-1}{4m^2-4m-3}\sin [(2m-1)x]$ and lets plot $F_1(x)$ against $f(x)$:

[image]

Now lets plot $F_{20}(x)$ against $f(x)$:

[image]

And this is what happens for $n=100$:

[image]

So can I say then say $F_n(x)$ converge to $\cos 2x$ on $(0,\pi)$ this sounds puzzling. Maybe I made a mistake. Could anyone please explain me what is going on here?

Comment: It looks like your function is a constant times x...

Comment: @TravisJ Many thanks, does it read better now?

Comment: Yes, much better.  I wasn't sure if the x was to be understood as part of the argument of the sine function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The series you got is the odd extension of this function to $[-\pi,\pi]$and periodic with period $2\pi$.

You are seeing in the partial sums the [Gibbs phenomenon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gibbs_phenomenon).

If you were to take the Cesaro sums of the series you would see it converge to $0$ at $x=0$ and similar points, see [Fejer's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fej%C3%A9r%27s_theorem).

Comment: Many thanks for the links and answer. I did not know Gibbs phenomenon. So you mean that $F_n(x)$ converges to zero at all points?

Comment: No, only at $x=k\pi$ the Cesaro sum of the series converges to $0$. In the interval $(0,\pi)$ it (the Cesaro sum of the series) converges to $\cos(2x)$. But in $(-\pi,0)$ it converges to $-\cos(2x)$. That is why it is not the Fourier of the even extension of the function $\cos(2x)$ in $[0,\pi]$, but the **odd** extension of it. Try making those plots but in $[-\pi,\pi]$ and you will see it happen.

Comment: This I see: at $x=k\pi$ I have that $\sin[(2m-1)k\pi]=0$, hence the sum is zero. But I thought I should figure out convergence for other points. Plotting on $(-\pi,0)$ I get $-\cos 2x$.

Comment: At the points in $(0,\pi)$ the series converges (the usual convergence) to $\cos(2x)$. [just because $\cos(2x)$ is differentiable there](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_Fourier_series#Pointwise_convergence).